# git update-ref appears to do nothing

Tags: git

At some point in the past someone deleted our `master` branch because we use `newmaster`. However, origin/HEAD is wrong:

```
$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
cat: .git/refs/remotes/origin/master: No such file or directory
```

This causes e.g. `git gc` to fail. I try to fix the situation like this:

```
git update-ref --create-reflog -m "Fix HEAD to be newmaster instead of non-existent master" refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/newmaster refs/remotes/origin/master
```

This fails with `fatal: refs/remotes/origin/master: not a valid old SHA1`, so it seems that I cannot fix a broken reference with `update-ref` doing validation. If I remove the old value then I get no output and a zero return code. However, nothing happens: I see the same content in `origin/HEAD` and `git gc` still throws an error:

```bash
$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
$ git gc
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
error: failed to run repack
```

**Questions:**

- what is the recommended way to fix this situation?
- are my syntax for `update-ref` and branch references correct?
- is either of the validation failure or the failure to act a bug in git?

Comment: Manually editing `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` to contain the `ref: refs/remotes/origin/newmaster` content fixes `git gc`.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a bug ([issues 423](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/423) in git for windows), which will be mitigated in git 2.7 (Q4 2015)

See [commit 14886b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14886b40c552d3ad4d5492d922948d76762af198), [commit 8c845cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c845cde99dcfc9821f1182623248dee9ebb4227) (28 Sep 2015) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b05c2f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b05c2f9ed48adfd9670b28ecdd5c55a4e4698704), 20 Oct 2015)</sup>

> ### `pack-objects`: do not get distracted by broken symrefs
>
> "`git gc`" used to barf when a symbolic ref has gone dangling (e.g. the branch that used to be your upstream's default when you cloned from it is now gone, and you did "`fetch --prune`").

[Here is a MVCE](https://github.com/dscho/git/commit/ec2bd787adbe75d4fba01f4977e0b24cc4ef48a6) ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

```
test_expect_failure 'gc removes stale refs/remotes/<name>/HEAD' '
    git init remote &&
    (
        cd remote &&
        test_commit initial &&
        git clone . ../client &&
        git branch -m develop &&
        cd ../client &&
        git fetch --prune &&
        git gc
    )
'
```

Comment: This indeed makes `git gc` more graceful. But I'm primarily asking about `update-ref`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that could be considered to be a bug in git.  In particular `git update-ref` should allow the "old" ref to be a string and should just do a direct string-compare.  What's happening here, I think, is that it's requiring both the command-line "old value" *and* the existing value to resolve to an actual commit-ID, which of course these don't.

I think you could do:

```
git update-ref --create-reflog \
  -m "Fix HEAD to be newmaster instead of non-existent master" \
  refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/newmaster
```

(i.e., take away the "expected old value" argument entirely), and it would probably work—not that I've actually tested it.

Comment: As per the question, removing the old value succeeds but doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Interesting.  Does the same go for updating it with `git symbolic-ref`?  Maybe git tries to treat `origin/HEAD` specially.

Comment: I'm not following you exactly - which part do you suggest doing with `git symbolic-ref`?

Comment: The `git update-ref` command is how you make a reference point to a specific SHA-1.  For `HEAD` (the regular `HEAD`) this gets you a "detached HEAD".  The `git symbolic-ref` command is basically equivalent to `git update-ref` but does not require SHA-1s, and is how you make `HEAD` point to a branch name, rather than a specific commit.  Normally `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, if it exists at all, is *also* an indirect reference, so perhaps updating it with `git symbolic-ref` will work; and perhaps git refuses to detach "remote HEADs".

Comment: `update-ref` does support dereferencing symbol references. I've just noticed that in my current version (2.6.0) there is a `--no-deref` option which possibly would have helped. The failure to update with no error or exit code still seems like a bug to me.